# MDCBottomDrawerViewController symbol not found

Tags: objective-c, mdc-components

I'm working on an iOS app and use a navigation drawer from material-io.
I use the example code, but I get error message when I run it.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    MDCBottomDrawerViewController *bottomDrawerViewController = [[MDCBottomDrawerViewController alloc] init];
    bottomDrawerViewController.contentViewController = [UIViewController new];
    bottomDrawerViewController.headerViewController = [UIViewController new];
    [self presentViewController:bottomDrawerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MDCBottomDrawerViewController
Referenced from: ***
in: ***/Frameworks/MaterialComponents.framework/MaterialComponents
```

Comment: Hoping you have properly imported the library.

Comment: @Aditya  I have already imported the library exactly.